# didReceiveLocalNotification fired twice

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I understand that `didReceiveLocalNotification` will fire twice. First it’ll fire when the local notification is fired and then when the user selects it.

Is there any way to know that the `didReceiveLocalNotification` is fired by user selection?

Currently when the notification fires (while keeping the app open), if I keep the drawer open the app automatically navigates to the screen. I don’t want it to happen. Only when user makes the selection it should navigate to specific screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When app is in state **inactive** (with OS notifications pulled down), the `didReceiveLocalNotification` seems to be called twice.
1. when notification arrives
2. if user taps on notification

What you can do is to catch **inactive** state at step 1 and do not perform your indented action.

Or you can do the opposite which is to remove the notification from notification center so as user can't tap it (step 2)

```
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Inactive) {
    application.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the Application is launch by notification, app delegate launch options should contain the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey` which in gives you the UILocalNotification associated with the notification.

if App is open and your target is iOS 8 then a new handler added

```
// Called when your app has been activated by the user selecting an action from a local notification.
// A nil action identifier indicates the default action.
// You should call the completion handler as soon as you've finished handling the action.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

also try to check if LocalNotification is cause the App launch then

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

when you are setting the local notification you can get the user dictionary in which you can set the Unique ID to keep track

```
notification.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:unique_id forKey:@"uniqueId"];
```

Comment: But my problem is when the app is opened and I'm pulling down the drawer of the notification screen. Then is there a way to know?? `didfinishlaunchingwithoptions` method will not be called in that instance right?